# Laravel - Show missed content

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel application, I have `Users` and `Posts`. What I'm trying to do is check whether any posts were created while a user was logged out and then display a message like 'Here's what you missed`, similar to Twitter.

I was thinking of having a table called `missed_content` that takes the user id, the model, and the model id, which I would cycle through for a given user and display the missed content.

So, a scheduled task would look for new content and add rows to this table if the `created_at` date of a post was after the user's `last_login_at` date.

Then when a user logs in I'd display the content and update `last_login_at`.

My concern is whether this would be scalable as if a million users missed 20 posts, that's 20 million records.

Comment: FYI, with proper indexes 20 million records is not that much.

Comment: Just use cached query when user logged in. After that display the "missed content". Thats much more stable as i thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make a last login on the user. and then get all posts that are made since that date?

```
$posts = Post::where('created_at', '<=', Auth::user()->last_sign_in)->get()
```

in your blade you can count it

```
<p>You have missed: {{ $posts->count() }} posts</p>
```

You wont need a extra table